# Post migration from one site to another site in a network

Tags: multisite, migration

I have a wordpress network site. I have many sites in my network. Lets say i have two subsites like wordpress.mysite.com,joomla.mysite.com.

If the user post wordpress related topic in joomla site then i would like to migrate it from joomla to wordpress. Just like stackoverflow.

Is there any good multisite plugin available for this feature?.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find best solution for this question.
If anyone have this question as mine then you may check this plugin. This is not the best one. But just a recommendation. 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multipost-mu/
It actually duplicate the post. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [AtomPub](http://codex.wordpress.org/AtomPub).

> AtomPub allows you to connect to your blog with an AtomPub-enabled
>   client and publish, update and delete posts and media files remotely,
>   without needing to log in to the administration section directly.

Answer (score 0):

With [ThreeWP Broadcast](http://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/) you can broadcast the post to another blog and then delete it from the current blog.